# Show that v is an eigenvector of the inverse of A times B, given two eigenpair equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Let *A* and *B* be $n$ x $n$ matrices, let det *A* $\neq$ $0$, and suppose, for some **v** $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{R}$

*A* **v** = $\lambda_A$**v** and *B* **v** = $\lambda_B$**v**.

Show that **v** is an eigenvector of *A*$^{-1}$*B*.

Find $\lambda_{A^{-1}B}$, the eigenvector associated to **v** as an eigenvector of *A*$^{-1}$*B*.

Here was my logic for the first part:
I multiplied *A*$^{-1}$ to both sides of *B* **v** = $\lambda_B$**v**

*A*$^{-1}$*B* **v** = *A*$^{-1}$$\lambda_B$**v**

= $\lambda_B$*A*$^{-1}$**v**

= $\lambda_B$$\lambda_C$**v** *

= $\lambda$**v**

$\therefore$ **v** is an eigenvector of *A*$^{-1}$*B*.

*my logic here was since det *A* $\neq$ $0$, **v** is an eigenvector of *A*$^{-1}$ since **v** is an eigenvector of *A*, so there is some $\lambda_C$ such that *A*$^{-1}$**v** = $\lambda_C$**v**

I'm not sure if this is correct and I'm not really sure how to start the second part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually much easier.

If you start out with $Av = \lambda_A v$, and $A$ being invertible, then just apply $A^{-1}$ to the above equation to get:
$$
A^{-1}(Av) = A^{-1} (\lambda_A) v \implies A^{-1}v = \frac{v}{\lambda_A}
$$

(Note that the eigenvalue has to be non-zero, since the determinant of $A$ is the product of it's eigenvalues, and that is non-zero)

Hence, the $\lambda_C$ which you have mentioned, is now known to you. That is , $\lambda_C = \frac 1{\lambda_A}$. Now, you can figure out the answer to both the first and second question (they come in one package).